# Add/Get value to CMFCPropertyGridCtrl

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm trying to get value from **MFC Property Grid Ctrl**.
Here is what I've tried:

```
CMFCPropertyGridCtrl *pValue = CMFCPropertyGridCtrl(_T("Test Value"));
pValue->AddSubItem(new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("Test value"),_T("15"),_T("Desc..."));

m_myPropGrid.AddProperty(pValue);

int x = m_myPropGrid.GetProperty(0).GetSubItem(0).iVal;//not return 15
```

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that Property Grid uses `_variant_t` to store values.
So you should specify integer instead of string type for your value:

```
_variant_t val = 15;    
pValue->AddSubItem(new CMFCPropertyGridProperty(_T("Test value"), val, _T("Description"));

int x = m_myPropGrid.GetProperty(0)->GetSubItem(0)->GetValue().iVal;
```

Comment: Right. I've made the changes to code snippet in my answer. So the compiler should now pick the proper overload of `AddSubItem`.

Comment: Its still not display the value

Comment: The way you are getting the value is also completely wrong. The `GetProperty` method returns the pointer to `CMFCPropertyGridProperty`. You should also call `GetValue()` to get the current value. Check updated code snippet for more info.